# Python warning print expression is assigned to nothing

Tags: python, python-3.x, linter

I'm using Syntastic in vim as a linter for Python3. I have a few warnings that my print statements are expressions that are not assigned to anything:

```
[expression-not-assigned] Expression "(print(('Authenticated for Twitter user ') + (twitter_api.VerifyCredentials().screen_name)), )" is assigned to nothing
[expression-not-assigned] Expression "(print('Deleting Twitter posts.'),     )" is assigned to nothing
```

These are just simple print statements so I'm curious why I'm seeing these warnings and how I would go about resolving them.

Comment: Did you put comma as the end of statement?

Comment: @yurikilochek Yes, in order to get things to print on new lines. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Well, turns out the commas were completely unnecessary... I feel dumb.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the outer parenthesizes and everything should be fine.

```
print('Authenticated for Twitter user %s' % twitter_api.VerifyCredentials().screen_name)
print('Deleting Twitter posts.')
```

Comment: That actually is how those statements appear in my code already.